# Javascript post request callback, redirect from .NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, fetch-api

I'm integrating PayPal checkout with an e-com solution, where upon PayPal successfully creating PayPal order/payment, I carry out some server side processing which eventually returns a `RedirectResult` (with a URL for payment failed or success accordingly) from my controller, back to the client/frontend.

I have the following code below, and was expecting it to redirect automatically, but no redirect occurrs.

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            intent: "CAPTURE",
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '5.20',
                }
            }]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            return fetch('/umbraco/surface/PayPalPayment/process', {
                method: 'post',
                redirect: 'follow',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    OrderID: data.orderID,
                    PayerID: data.payerID,
                }),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        }).catch(error=>console.log("Error capturing order!", error));
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

If I explicitly redirect with the code below, then the action carries out.

```
onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            return fetch('/umbraco/surface/PayPalPayment/process', {
                method: 'post',
                redirect: 'follow',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    OrderID: data.orderID,
                    PayerID: data.payerID,
                }),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function () { window.location.replace('https://www.google.co.uk') });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error capturing order!", error);
            window.location.replace('https://www.bbc.co.uk');
        });
    }
```

Basically, I'm wondering why fetch redirect does not follow the Redirect that is returned form my controller. Controller redirect for full completeness:

```
return new RedirectResult("/checkout/thank-you") ;
```

Comment: `Basically, I'm wondering why fetch redirect does not follow the Redirect that is returned form my controller`- Would you explain this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase your question

You want to know why the **browser** did not redirect after you made a `fetch` - even though `fetch` api response
was a `RedirectResult`

The reason is simple, you made a request in `fetch`, which means you are making ajax request (hence browser will not change)

you set the `redirect` to `follow`, which means after the first request (i.e after get response from 
`/umbraco/surface/PayPalPayment/process`), it will **follow** to the url `/checkout/thank-you`
so, what you get in the `then()` will be the response of `/checkout/thank-you`

so overall, it did follow the response but maybe not the way you expected (follow within the ajax request, not browser changing the page)

If what you want is a redirect to specific page, after the success call to `/umbraco/surface/PayPalPayment/process`

Then do:

1. Modify your backend to return `JsonResult` of the url instead of `RedirectResult`

```
return Json(new {redirectUrl = "/checkout/thank-you"});
```

2. use `then` to redirect

```
// other code omitted

.then(function (response) { return response.json(); })
.then(function (data) {window.location.replace(data.redirectUrl)});
```